# How to get date "hh:mm:ss" format using php

Tags: php

I am retrieving date from the url 
`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
&videoSyndicated=true
&type=video
&id=CRvoJEqrYTY
&key=AIzaSyD68YEP1N9J0-umFWuzMV3NEN3T5VBvoHo`
```

as `PT1H8M21S`. How to convert it into `hh:mm:ss` using php

Comment: what do you try to do ? i don't understand the question

Comment: i am trying to convert "PT1H8M21S" into php date format "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: an what makes you think that's a time format ?

Comment: @lalith458 next time you should specify in your question that the requested solution must be compatible with PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1):

The string `'PT1H8M21S'` it's not a Date, or a Time. It's an interval (specifically, it's a [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) string representation ).

You need a baseline DateTime to add that interval.

Try something along these lines

```
$interval = $dv = new DateInterval('PT1H8M21S'); //the value you get from the url
$time = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); //any date works fine here. 
                                    // Note: Hours, mins and seconds == 0
$time->add($interval);
echo $time->format('H:i:s');
```

First, create the proper DateInterval object from the string you received.

Then, create a baseline DateTime object. Any date is ok, you just need to make sure that you have hours, minutes and seconds (I'm assuming that the interval will always be less than one full day.)

Add the interval to the baseline date and echo the hours, minutes and seconds as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) function like this

```
$time = "PT1H8M21S";
$time = str_replace("PT", "", $time);
$time = str_replace("H", ":", $time);
$time = str_replace("M", ":", $time);
$time = str_replace("S", "", $time);
echo $time;
```

maybe you can add zero padding in your final string if you like it

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.+)M(.+)S$/', $str, $m3); echo $m3[1].":".$m3[2].":".$m3[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

change $youtube_time to your interval variable

```
$youtube_time = 'PT1H8M21S';
$duration = new DateInterval($youtube_time);
$videoDuration = (60 * 60 * $duration->h) + (60 * $duration->i) + $duration->s;
print gmdate("H:i:s", $videoDuration);
```

Comment: thanks, i got the solution, whether it supports for all php versions?

Comment: it's supported on PHP 5.3.0+

Comment: k. can u tell me the code which supports for all versions, because my server php version is "5.2.17"

Comment: @lalith458 upgrade your php

Comment: k.. there is any method to convert it which suports in all php versions

Comment: you should really update your version of PHP. 5.2 is deprecated and had it's End Of Life on 6 Jan 2011 ( http://www.php.net/eol.php )

Answer (score -1):

If you think that 1H8M21S means 1 Hour 8 minute & 21 seconds then use preg macth to get the values.

```
$str = 'PT1H8M21S';preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.*)/', $str, $m);echo $m[1];
```

Comment: yes, that means 1 hour. You can write same code for minutes & seconds

Comment: Can you change your answer so it also gives the minutes and seconds.

Comment: Ok check this
`$str = 'PT1H8M21S';

preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.*)/', $str, $m);
echo $m[1];
preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.+)M(.+)/', $str, $m2);
echo $m2[2];
preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.+)M(.+)S$/', $str, $m3);
print_r($m3[3]);`

Comment: Really? 3 preg_matches? Why not in one?

Comment: yep you can use the last preg match only.

Comment: `preg_match('/PT(.+)H(.+)M(.+)S$/', $str, $m3); echo $m3[1].":".$m3[2].":".$m3[3]`

Comment: Put that as your answer.

Comment: but it is not useful for string "PT1M2S","PT1H2S" etc